# Cant Find Xampp setup for windows 32 bit (Php 7.3.2 )

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I have Windows 7 32 bits system , when i go to official website https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html .

Its showing only 64 bit version for windows os , even i download this 64 bit version of xampp and try to install on 32 bits windows pc , it gives me error .

please share me the link where i can download Xampp setup for windows 32 bit (Php 7.3.2 )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Downloaded version 7.3.2 here, working fine

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.3.2/

this file does't work on 32-bit window

Comment: Is this the last version compatible with Windows 7 32 bit?

Comment: I think the one you want in that link is: xampp-win32-7.3.2-0-VC15-installer.exe